# Filter array by first letter of string property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, filter, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` with objects that have a `name` property.

I would like filter the array by `name`

```
    NSString *alphabet = [agencyIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSMutableArray *listSimpl = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[[Database sharedDatabase].agents count]; i++) {
        Town *_town = [[Database sharedDatabase].agents objectAtIndex:i];
        [listSimpl addObject:_town];
    }
    NSArray *states = [listSimpl filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But I get an error - "Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = <1, Arrow> rhs = A)"

How can I do this?  I would like to filter the array for the first letter in `name` being 'A'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: No, i would like to filter by first letter - "A"

Comment: The most important piece of code for this post is the predicate itselft but was left out.  Show how you defined the predicate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try with following code

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", yourName];
NSArray *filteredArr = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

**EDITED :**

`NSPredicate` pattern should be:

```
NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
```

Comment: Not working( Error - Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = <1, Arraow> rhs = А)

Comment: @please put your array list and explain me what you want ?

Comment: @Nubaslon- change NSPredicate pattern such like `SELF beginswith[c] %@`

Comment: Array contains object of class Town, Town has property - id, name

Comment: Then what is `NSLog(@"%@",listSimpl);`

Comment: <1, Москва, 55.755772, 37.617760, 0>
<762, Russia, 48.736416, 44.493610, 0>
<2000000307, Tel Aviv, 50.929810, 6.955242, 0>
<2000001662, Abakan, 53.720978, 91.442421, 0>
<2000002332, Azov, 47.092899, 39.426750, 0>
<12029, Actobe, 50.300411, 57.154591, 0>
<970, Berkut, 56.392387, 38.726463, 0>
<798, Bolinsk, 43.238274, 76.945465, 0>
<2000001633, Bolshevik, 54.900482, 52.306652, 0>
<312, Vilnus, 44.891445, 37.321228, 0>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37087/discussion-between-nubaslon-and-ipatel)

Answer (score 10):

Here is one of the basic use of NSPredicate for filtering array .

```
NSMutableArray *array =
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", @"arbind", nil];

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b'"];
NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
NSLog(@"beginwithB = %@",beginWithB);
```

Answer (score 3):

NSArray offers another selector for sorting arrays:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *first, Person *second) {
    return [first.name compare:second.name];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **filter** array take a look on this code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", @"qwe"];
NSArray *result = [self.categoryItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But if you want to **sort** array take a look on the following functions:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context;
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context hint:(NSData *)hint;
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
```

Answer (score 0):

visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html

use this

```
[listArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library

https://github.com/BadChoice/Collection

It comes with lots of easy array functions to never write a loop again

So you can just do

```
NSArray* result = [thArray filter:^BOOL(NSString *text) {
    return [[name substr:0] isEqualToString:@"A"]; 
}] sort];
```

This gets only the texts that start with A sorted alphabetically

If you are doing it with objects:

```
NSArray* result = [thArray filter:^BOOL(AnObject *object) {
    return [[object.name substr:0] isEqualToString:@"A"]; 
}] sort:@"name"];
```