# How to replace the value of the key in NSMutableDictionary based on the another key value pair

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdictionary

I have one `NSArray` with `NSMutableDictionaries` .Example `testArray =[dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4].`
Each dictionary in the array is something like

```
dict1=  {
    country = "INDIA";
    flag = "A";
    Currency = "Rupees";
    rate = 10;
}
```

The all values are changeable. Sometimes

```
dict1 = {
    country = "USA";
    flag = "SA";
    Currency = "Dollar";
    rate = 50;
   }
```

I need to update the value of the key rate of all  dictionaries in the testArray if  `country = "INDIA"` and `flag = "A"` and `Currency = "Rupees"` and Do not need to change the value of the rate key all other dictionaries in side the testArray.

Comment: See this topic, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/18714634/2673612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try the below.

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dic in array)
{
    if([[dic valueForKey:@"country"] isEqualToString:@"INDIA"] &&
       [[dic valueForKey:@"flag"] isEqualToString:@"A"] &&
       [[dic valueForKey:@"Currency"] isEqualToString:@"Rupees"])
    {
        [dic setValue:@"100" forKey:@"rate"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example what you need

```
NSDictionary *dict1 =  @{
                             @"country" : @"INDIA",
                             @"flag" : @"A",
                             @"Currency" : @"Rupees",
                             @"rate" : @10
                             };
    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                            @"country" : @"USA",
                            @"flag" : @"SA",
                            @"Currency" : @"Dollar",
                            @"rate" : @50
                            };
    NSArray *testArray = @[dict1, dict2];
    NSMutableArray *testMutableArray = [testArray mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < testMutableArray.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *country = testMutableArray[i];
        if ([country[@"country"] isEqualToString:@"INDIA"] &&
            [country[@"flag"] isEqualToString:@"A"] &&
            [country[@"Currency"] isEqualToString:@"Rupees"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *countryMutable = [country mutableCopy];
            countryMutable[@"rate"] = @100;
            testMutableArray[i] = [countryMutable copy];
        }
    }
    testArray = [testMutableArray copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray.

then,

```
NSDictionary *dict = [testArray objectAtIndex:0];

dict[@"rate"] = @"11";

[testArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dict];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Heh, seems you're a wizard, you are mutating an immutable object.