# How to filter NSArray in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
self.filteredUserData = self.userData.filter({( listing: NSDictionary) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = listing["name"].rangeOfString(searchText)
        return stringMatch != nil
})
```

I was going to do something like above, but I realized `'NSArray' does not have a member named 'filter'` and not a Swift Array. How can I filter NSArrays in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter array with objects by using predicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714634/how-to-filter-array-with-objects-by-using-predicate)

Comment: lol this is not an objective-c question. completely different syntax.

Comment: You're not listening. Your question is not a _language_ question. It's a Cocoa / Foundation question (that's what NSArray is). You need to be language-agnostic if you want to work with Cocoa methods. The "translation" from that answer to yours is trivial; a machine could do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
self.filteredUserData = self.userData.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
```

Objective-C version:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
self.filteredUserData = [self.userData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Comment: So you did the second thing that I suggested. So how is this different from what I said?

Comment: Well I actually wrote the code to show how different the syntax is.