# iOS: how to filter array from another array based on parameter value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, filtering

I have an `NSArray` (DataArray) whose response is as follows:

```
  {
"id": "17",
"item_name": "Chivito",
"item_price": "88.00",
"item_status": "Y",
"is_admin": "0",
"item_quantity": "120",
"status": 0
},
  {
"id": "14",
"item_name": "Doughnut",
"item_price": "50.00",
"item_status": "Y",
"is_admin": "0",
"item_quantity": "100",
"status": 1
},
  {
"id": "37",
"item_name": "Drink test ",
"item_price": "80.00",
"item_status": "Y",
"is_admin": "0",
"item_quantity": "12",
"status": 1
},
```

I have to create another filtered array of only those object whose status value is "1"
Please help me how to do it

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955162/how-to-filter-nsarray-in-swift ?

Comment: Read the docs... Read the other SO questions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110332/filtering-nsarray-into-a-new-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to @Hady ans, In Objective-C you can do it as. Forgive if there are any formatting/syntax issues. I am away from my system.

```
NSMutableArry *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (i=0;i<dataArray.count;i++)
{
   if([dataArray[i][@"status"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1]])      //if(dataArray[i]["status"] == 1)
    {
      [filteredArray addObject:dataArray[i]];
     }
 }
```

Hope it helps.. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Just because that is how it is done in Swift does not mean that it is done that way in Objective-C.

Comment: Code above will give required results. I didnt just translated it. I really dont think it deserves a downvote!!!

Comment: thanks it works i replace if(dataArray[i]["status"] == 1)  with   if([DataArray[i][@"status"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1]])

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept my ans if it helped you. Actually I were unaware of data format. Thanks for edit.

Comment: @luckyShubhra it might work. Just like the other 2 answers work. Except this answer has 8 lines of code as opposed to 2. But other than that. There are hundreds of other SO questions asking the exact same thing. So this question shouldn't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
array.filter{(object) -> Bool in 
  if let object = object as NSDictionary {
    if let status = object["status"] as? Int {
      return status == 1
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Check my ans in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Try predicate its easy and less looping .

> NSPredicate *sizePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status
> ==  %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
>
> NSMutableArray * filteredSizeArray = [self.arrayFilter filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sizePredicate].copy;

Answer (score -1):

Try:

**OBJECTIVE-C:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.status == %d",1];
    NSArray *filtered = [DataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", filtered);
```

Comment: @downVoters Why so much downVotes? Using `predicate` will also work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
NSPredicate *prediate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %d",1];
arrResult = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:prediate];
```