# NSPredicate for filtering array with ( ' ) character issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

Here is my test for filtering the array by a string. It work well if my string doesn't contain (') character

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"b'en", @"Adam", @"Melissa", @"arbind", nil];

    //NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b'"]; -> it work
    NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b''"]; -> it crash
    NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
    NSLog(@"beginwithB = %@",beginWithB);
```

I also try to change my string to `'b\''` or `'b'''` but it still crash

Here is the crash log

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF contains[c] 'b'''"'

How to resolve it? Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but `contains` sounds like a bad candidate for a predicate whose results are named `beginWith...`

Comment: @Alladinian yes, it only my test, I just copy this code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738783/5381331. thank you for you correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to filter result as follows:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"b'en", @"Adam", @"Melissa", @"arbind", nil];
        NSString *strToBeSearched = @"b'";

        //NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b'"]; -> it work

        NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",strToBeSearched]; //-> it also work

        //OR

        NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b\\''"];


        NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
        NSLog(@"containB = %@",beginWithB);
```

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
NSString *searchword = @"b";
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchword];
```

you get output of

[image]

Comment: if you want the excat answer use daskblinkknight answer , else try my answer

Comment: you provide a correct solution but the way you show me is not very good. because I ask about the string that a (') character but in your test your string doesn't contains ('). anyway thank you so much for give me a correct solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close when you tried backslash. This is the character that `NSPredicate` uses to escape special characters. However, you need two, not one, backslash:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"b'en", @"Adam", @"Melissa", @"arbind", nil];
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'b\\''"];
//                                                                              ^^
NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
NSLog(@"beginwithB = %@",beginWithB);
```

The reason you need two is Objective-C compiler. It processes all string literals in your code, and replaces escape sequences it encounters. If you would like `NSPredicate` to see a single backslash, your string literal needs to have two backslashes, because backslash itself is encoded as `\\` in Objective-C string literals.

Answer (score 0):

If your name is b'en then,

```
 NSString *name = @"b'en";
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == \"%@\"", name];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: it crash with the error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'`. I have found the solution. thank for your help